# Deduplicating assets in a monorepo

Tags: reactjs, lerna, monorepo

My file structure is as follows:

```
- packages
    - app1
        - node_modules
            - shared
        - public
            - svg1
        - src/pages
    - app2
        - node_modules
            - shared
        - public
            - svg1
        - src/pages
    - shared
        - src/components
```

I'm using Lerna to share React components in the `shared` package with my `app1` and `app2` packages, so for example, my `app1` `package.json.dependencies` includes `"shared": "^1.0.0"`.

I have no problems sharing components, but I'm unsure how to share assets (like .png and .svg files). What currently works is to add all assets (see svg1) to the `public` folder in *both* the `app1` and `app2` packages, but I'd like to deduplicate them.

For example, in one of my `shared` components, I'm referencing a .svg simply with `<img src="svg1.svg" alt="MyLogo" />`, but the image only loads in `app1` if it's included in the `app1` package.

How can I keep these assets in the `shared` package and reference them in an `app1`, `app2`, or `shared` component?